# Dynamically added data not saving into database using django

Tags: mysql, django, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9PWN.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUuFJ.png)

Dynamically added value not saving into data base. the value are saved only what we are given first time. and the additional added data not saving into database.

Comment: I think you should provide more  codes for others to read.  check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Kindly help me to doing this work.   Thanks in advance..

Comment: yes, I and someone will help you if they know what's causing the problem (you should provide all the codes that is link or related to the issues you are dealing with. That's why I asked you to ask a good question based on this link  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: yes i have provided

Answer (score 0):

```
Models.py:

class ordernewmodel(models.Model):   
    process_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    machine = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    add_info = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


forms.py:

class ordernewform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ordernewmodel
        fields = "__all__"




Views.py:


def ordernewview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       
        if request.POST.get('process_name ') and  request.POST.get('machine') and request.POST.get('add_info')) :
            ordsave = ordernewmodel()          
            ordsave.process_name= request.POST.get('process_name')
            ordsave.machine= request.POST.get('machine')
            ordsave.add_info= request.POST.get('add_info')
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("call orderordernew('"ordsave.process_name"' +'"ordsave.machine"' +'"ordsave.qty"' )")
            return render(request, 'my-order.html')
        else:
            print("nothing has to be print")
            return render(request, 'ordernew.html')
   
my-order.html:


<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
        
        <div class="card-body">
            <form id="myform" method="POST" action="/ordernewview/">
                {% csrf_token %}
                
                <div id="second">
                    <div class="row">
                        
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="bmd-label-floating"></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="process_name" id="process_name" placeholder="process_name" />
                            {{ form.process_name }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="bmd-label-floating"></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="machine" id="machine" placeholder="machine" />
                            {{ form.machine }}
                        </div>                    

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="bmd-label-floating"></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="add_info" id="add_info"
                                placeholder="add_info" />
                            {{ form.add_info }}
                        </div>
                       
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="vendor" &nbsp;
                            value="add vendor" />
                        <input onclick="addRow(this.form)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ;" &nbsp;
                            value="add process" />

                    </div>
                </div>               
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var rowNum = 0;
    function addRow(frm) {
        rowNum++;
        var row = '<label id="rowNum' + rowNum + '"><div class="col-md-3"><label class="bmd-label-floating"></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="process_name" id="process_name" placeholder="process_name" />< input type = "text" class="form-control" name = "machine[]" value = "' + frm.machine.value + '"  id = "machine" placeholder = "machine" /><input type="text" class="form-control" name="add_info[]" value="' + frm.add_info.value + '" id="add_info" placeholder="add_info" /></div><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow(' + rowNum + ');"></label>';
        jQuery('#second').append(row);
        frm.process_name.value = '';
        frm.machine.value = '';   
        frm.add_info.value = '';
    }
    function removeRow(rnum) {
        jQuery('#rowNum' + rnum).remove();
    }
</script>
{% endblock content %}


<!-- Specific Page JS goes HERE  -->
{% block javascripts %}{% endblock javascripts %}
```

Comment: please help me to do this.

Comment: No one is helping me